# Duplicate effort when switching branches? reinstall dependencies?

Tags: git, github, branch

For example, I worked on a branch called abc, and installed dependencies and added code in package.json, setupTests.js, .gitignore etc.

and the branch abc is now under PR.(so everything from abc is not in master)

now i am working on a newly created branch, and you can guess all dependencies i installed and configured etc that done on branch abc is not here, so request me to re-do all these.

I wonder what is the best solution or if you also undergone such thing? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue working on changes from a previous branch where the changes are not yet in the master branch (as example under review, PR), then simply create a new branch on top of the old (`abc`) branch.

```
git checkout abc
git checkout -b <new-branch>
```

So you have all the previously created changes in your new branch.

But beware (!!!): if something is criticized in the open PR from branch `abc` and new changes are pushed, these changes must also be merged into the newly created branch in order to avoid conflicts.

```
git checkout <new-branch>
git merge abc
```

If the open PR from branch `abc` is approved, merged in `master` and the branch deleted, the source branch from `new-branch` will changed automatically to the source branch from the deleted `abc`, and this would be `master`. So you didn‘t have to change anything.